# Netlify Insecure mixed content detected in

Tags: git, netlify

Every time I push changes into my private repo I got an email with that specif alert.
Im using the free service to deploy my website.

```html
11:31:51 AM: Build ready to start
11:31:53 AM: build-image version: 6dfe19d15f524c85d6f9bf7df9fb30b0a9f0a61a
11:31:53 AM: build-image tag: v3.3.10
11:31:53 AM: buildbot version: 6bb3f784302b4ad90de13035b247a363a8bee34a
11:31:53 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:31:53 AM: Starting to download cache of 1020.9KB
11:31:53 AM: Finished downloading cache in 240.397634ms
11:31:53 AM: Starting to extract cache
11:31:53 AM: Finished extracting cache in 18.733503ms
11:31:53 AM: Finished fetching cache in 259.927406ms
11:31:53 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:31:54 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
11:31:55 AM: No build command found, continuing to publishing
11:31:55 AM: Starting to deploy site from '/'
11:31:55 AM: Creating deploy tree 
11:31:55 AM: Creating deploy upload records
11:31:55 AM: 1 new files to upload
11:31:55 AM: 0 new functions to upload
11:31:55 AM: Starting post processing
11:31:55 AM: Mixed content detected in: /index.html
11:31:55 AM: --> insecure link urls:
11:31:55 AM:   - http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans
11:31:55 AM: Finished processing build request in 2.546374247s
11:31:55 AM: Post processing done
11:31:56 AM: Site is live
```

Comment: [What is "mixed content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content). The cause of the error: "*insecure link*" **http://** must be **httpS://**

Comment: The error in your **/index.html**, not in the file you linked.

Comment: thanks, will fix the https fonts error, or look a different fonts to remove it

Answer (score -1):

There is a meta tag that can automatically upgrade http to https.

```
// meta tag
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) upgrade-insecure-requests directive instructs user agents to treat all of a site's insecure URLs (those served over HTTP) as though they have been replaced with secure URLs (those served over HTTPS). This directive is intended for web sites with large numbers of insecure legacy URLs that need to be rewritten.